# Is it possible to fetch the parent object heading to the child object in doors module?

Tags: ibm-doors

I want to write a dxl code which checks the object's parent heading(object level 3) and writes in a separate column for all the child objects.
Can anyone please help me with dxl command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to create layout DXL column with the following approach

```
Object oParent = parent(obj)
if (!null oParent) {
    if (!null oParent."Object Heading""") {
        display oParent."Object Heading"""
    }
}
```

You might want to augment the code with some conditions, like `if/and level(obj) == 3` (i.e. only show something if the level of the CURRENT object is 3) or `if/and (!null obj."Object Heading""")` (i.e. don't show the parent's heading if the CURRENT object owns a heading).

Comment: Thank you Mike, I got exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @Megha May please accept the answer if it solved your problem to keep up SO spirit. and also as a ping to Mike about your [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56536641/what-is-a-vba-command-to-close-read-only-modules-along-with-doors-application-it).