# what is a vba command to close read-only modules along with doors application itself

Tags: vba, ibm-doors

Is there any command to close read only Doors modules and then close the doors application itself?

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what is Doors Module ?

Comment: In IBM Rational Doors, Projects and folders are used to organize and structure the data in the database and it contains the folder and formal modules. Doors module here is formal module which contains objects and those are defined by their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Closing the application itself is accomplish with the command:

```
exit_
```

This will close your instance of DOORS. Use carefully- no DXL code after this call will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, in case you have not already solved that part: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=7a01e109-c6a2-443b-a3df-15f781b70c08 shows how to connect to an existing DOORS application.

Closing read only modules explicitely is not needed if you plan to exit DOORS, as the DOORS client will close all read only modules.

You should rather care about modules that have been opened in edit mode and where things have already been changed. Not sure if it wise, but if you want something like an auto-save-and-close, you would probably need this DXL script

```
Module m
for m in database do {
    if (unsaved m) {
        save m
    }
}
exit_
```

This will not help you in all situations, e.g. if you have made changes to the current view, DOORS will ask you for a confirmation. For this, you might have to load the Standard view in all modules. More problems might occur.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the DOORS instance use : `exit_`.